# how to edit the end of each line in a .csv file with the same data

Tags: python, java, excel, csv

I have attempted to look around but have not found many solutions that are similar. I am sure it is a relatively easy solution that I am overlooking.

I would like to add the same information at the end of every line of a `.csv`. I tried moving the `.csv` file into excel and manually editing and then converting it back to a `.csv` but it does not move over to Tableau in a compatible manner, as that is where the `.csv` file will be ending up as a scatter plot. Doing it manually for 450 lines is counterproductive. I have tried using a separate file that can be attached but again going into tableau it does not work well.

The line below is what the data looks like and at the end I need to add `D11`

```
0,-11.0,0022-03-01 1:05:29.70,611846.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your file format is CSV, i assume that you don't want to add just `D11`, but also another CSV field separator, which seems to be `,`. The following python script reads a file `input.csv` and writes a new file `output.csv`, with an additional `,D11` at the end of each line.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3                                                                                                 

import sys

additionalText=",D11"
inputfile='input.csv'
sys.stdout = open('output.csv', 'w')

with open(inputfile) as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.rstrip() + additionalText)
```